# Definition by property in coq

Tags: coq

I am having trouble with formalizing definitions of the following form: define an integer such that some property holds.

Let's say that I formalized the definition of the property:

```
Definition IsGood (x : Z) : Prop := ...
```

Now I need a definition of the form:

```
Definition Good : Z := ...
```

assuming that I proved that an integer with the property exists and is unique:

```
Lemma Lemma_GoodExistsUnique : exists! (x : Z), IsGood x.
```

Is there an easy way of defining `Good` using `IsGood` and `Lemma_GoodExistsUnique`?

Since, the property is defined on integer numbers, it seems that no additional axioms should be necessary. In any event, I don't see how adding something like the axiom of choice can help with the definition.

Also, I am having trouble with formalizing definitions of the following form (I suspect this is related to the problem I described above, but please indicate if that is not the case): for every `x`, there exists `y`, and these `y` are different for different `x`. Like, for example, how to define that there are `N` distinct good integer numbers using `IsGood`:

```
Definition ThereAreNGoodIntegers (N : Z) (IsGood : Z -> Prop) := ...?
```

In real-world mathematics, definitions like that occur every now and again, so this should not be difficult to formalize if Coq is intended to be suitable for practical mathematics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer to your first question is: in general, it is not possible, but in your particular case, yes.

In Coq's theory, propositions (i.e., `Prop`s) and their proofs have a very special status. In particular, it is in general not possible to write a choice operator that extracts the witness of an existence proof. This is done to make the theory compatible with certain axioms and principles, such as proof irrelevance, which says that all proofs of a given proposition are equal to each other. If you want to be able to do this, you need to add this choice operator as an additional axiom to your theory, as in the [standard library](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Logic.Epsilon.html).

However, in certain particular cases, it *is* possible to extract a witness out of an abstract existence proof without recurring to any additional axioms. In particular, it is possible to do this for countable types (such as `Z`) when the property in question is decidable. You can for instance use the `choiceType` interface in the [Ssreflect](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/~jenkins/current/mathcomp.ssreflect.choice.html) library to get exactly what you want (look for the `xchoose` function).

That being said, I would usually advice *against* doing things in this style, because it leads to unnecessary complexity. It is probably easier to define `Good` directly, without resorting to the existence proof, and then prove separately that `Good` has the sought property.

```
Definition Good : Z := (* ... *)
Definition IsGood (z : Z) : Prop := (* ... *)

Lemma GoodIsGood : IsGood Good.
Proof. (* ... *) Qed.

Lemma GoodUnique : forall z : Z, IsGood z -> z = Good.
```

If you absolutely want to define `Good` with an existence proof, you can also change the proof of `Lemma_GoodExistsUnique` to use a connective in `Type` instead of `Prop`, since it allows you to extract the witness directly using the `proj1_sig` function:

```
Lemma Lemma_GoodExistsUnique : {z : Z | Good z /\ forall z', Good z' -> z' = z}.
Proof. (* ... *) Qed.
```

As for your second question, yes, it is a bit related to the first point. Once again, I would recommend that you write down a function `y_from_x` with type `Z -> Z` that will compute `y` given `x`, and then prove separately that this function relates inputs and outputs in a particular way. Then, you can say that the `y`s are different for different `x`s by proving that `y_from_x` is injective.

On the other hand, I'm not sure how your last example relates to this second question. If I understand what you want to do correctly, you can write something like

```
Definition ThereAreNGoodIntegers (N : Z) (IsGood : Z -> Prop) :=
  exists zs : list Z,
    Z.of_nat (length zs) = N
    /\ NoDup zs
    /\ Forall IsGood zs.
```

Here, `Z.of_nat : nat -> Z` is the canonical injection from naturals to integers, `NoDup` is a predicate asserting that a list doesn't contain repeated elements, and `Forall` is a higher-order predicate asserting that a given predicate (in this case, `IsGood`) holds of all elements of a list.

As a final note, I would advice against using `Z` for things that can only involve natural numbers. In your example, your using an integer to talk about the cardinality of a set, and this number is always a natural number.