# How to prove a prove definition in Coq

Tags: types, pattern-matching, definition, coq, proof

I am currently working with Coq and I am encountering a problem that I don't know how to solve.

Let's say we are working with a given type, I'll take `nat` for the example, and I want to use a function `f` that might fail. To compensate the failure, we define `f` to be of type `nat -> option nat`.

Now I have a given hypothesis `H: nat -> bool` under which f doesn't fail, and I have even proved the lemma

```
Lemma no_error_in_f : forall (n:nat), H n = true -> exists (u:nat), f n = Some u.
```

I want to define a function `g: nat->nat` which gives the result of `f` on `n` if `H n` is satisfied, and just gives `n` otherwise. This function should be well defined, but I don't know how to define it properly.
If I try something naive like
`Definition g (n:nat) := if H n then f n else n.`, there is a problem in the typing system.

Does anyone knows how to gather all the elements and tell the system that the definition is legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give here a solution that works with the same hypotheses as the ones given in the question.

```
Axiom f : nat -> option nat.
Axiom H : nat -> bool.
Axiom no_error_in_f : forall n,
  H n = true -> exists u, f n = Some u.

Lemma no_error_in_f_bis : forall n,
  H n = true -> f n <> None.
Proof.
  intros. apply no_error_in_f in H0. destruct H0. rewrite H0. discriminate.
Qed.

Definition g n :=
  match H n as b return H n = b -> _ with
  | true => fun H =>
    match f n as f0 return f n = f0 -> _ with
    | Some n0 => fun _ => n0
    | None => fun H0 => match no_error_in_f_bis n H H0 with end
    end eq_refl
  | false => fun _ => n
  end eq_refl.
```

I use another lemma than `no_error_in_f`, which is more convenient to prove `False`.
Note that the two ideas of this function (use the `return` construct of `match`, destruct a proof of `False` to show that a branch is not reachable) are explained here: http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Subset.html.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your development. One is that you cannot use `no_error_in_f` to define `g` in Coq without assuming additional axioms, because Coq does not allow to extract computational information from a proof (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30171995/definition-by-property-in-coq/30174830#30174830) for more details). Another problem is that you can't use `H` in an `if` expression, because it returns a `Prop` instead of a `bool` (check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554453/why-are-logical-connectives-and-booleans-separate-in-coq/31568076#31568076) for more details).

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, the second error does not appear, because `H n` is of type `bool` and my lemma has as predicate `H n = true`. I will edit this. For the first problem, I thought of something like False_rec, or something like that

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to do this, here is my solution if anyone is interested:

`Definition g (n:nat) :nat :=
      (match (H n) as a return a = H n -> nat with
        | true => 
           (fun H_true => (match (f n) as b return b = f n -> nat with
                           | Some u => (fun _ => u)
                           | None => (fun H1 => False_rec _ (no_error_in_f H_true H1))
                           end) (eq_refl f n))
        | false => n
        end) (eq_refl H n).`

For those who would like to know what it means, False_rec take as a second argument a proof of False and certifies that the matching is not possible.
the term

`(match (f n) as b return b = f n -> nat with
       | Some u => (fun _ => u)
       | None => (fun H1 => False_rec _ (no_error_in_f H_true H1))
     end) (eq_refl f n))`
has type `f n = f n-> nat` and when I apply it to the proof `eq_refl (f n)` (which is a proof that f n = f n, so is typed `f n = f n`), I obtain a `nat`.
This a trick that allows me to obtain `H1` which is a proof that `f n = None` obtained using the reflexevity of equality and the pattern-matching, and that I am goin to use in my proof of `False`.

Same goes for the other match.

Comment: I understand the idea, but your solution does not typecheck as is. Could you correct it so that it works with the hypotheses given in your question ?